# How can I make a fullscreen overlay on the OS X desktop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, overlay

I want to make some kind of drawable surface that exists beneath the mouse cursor but above everything else rendered on the desktop.  I am trying to create a "trail" behind the mouse.

How can I do this in Cocoa and Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass `NSWindow` to create a borderless window and set its window level to something like `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel - 1`.

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect 
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self=[super initWithContentRect:contentRect 
                          styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                            backing:bufferingType
                              defer:flag];

    if(self!=nil)
    {
        [self setHasShadow:NO];
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [self setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel - 1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be "always on top" of every other window, nor is it transparent.  Why is that?

Comment: How did you create your window?

Comment: I tried making the subclass you recommended and instantiating it from my AppDelegate.  As far as I could tell, the over-ridden constructor never got called.  I switched to creating the window in the AppDelegate directly and setting those properties on it.  That worked.